# Pass default parameters to container in apache-mesos

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I'm trying to pass default parameters such as volumes or envs to my docker container, which I create through Marathon and Apache Mesos. It is possible through arguments passed to mesos-slave. I've put in `/etc/mesos-slave/default_container_info` file with JSON content (mesos-slave read this file and put it as its arguments):

```
{
  "type": "DOCKER",
  "volumes": [
    {
      "host_path": "/var/lib/mesos-test",
      "container_path": "/tmp",
      "mode": "RW"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I've restarted mesos-slave and create new container in marathon, but I can not see mounted volume in my container. Where I could do mistake? How can I pass default values to my containers in other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work for you. When you schedule task on Marathon with docker, Marathon creates TaskInfo with ContainerInfo and that's why Mesos do not fill your default.

From the [documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/)

> `--default_container_info=VALUE` JSON-formatted ContainerInfo that will be included into any ExecutorInfo that does **not** specify a ContainerInfo

You need to add volumes to every Marathon task you have or create [`RunSpecTaskProcessor`](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/master/plugin-interface/src/main/scala/mesosphere/marathon/plugin/task/RunSpecTaskProcessor.scala) that will augment all tasks with your volumes

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!